# Caret confusionMatrix measures are wrong?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I made a function to compute sensitivity and specificity from a confusion matrix, and only later found out the `caret` package has one, `confusionMatrix()`. When I tried it, things got very confusing as it appears `caret` is using the wrong formulae??

Example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(real = as.factor(c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1)),
                  pred = as.factor(c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0)))
cm <- table(dat$real, dat$pred)
cm
    0 1
  0 1 1
  1 2 5
```

My function:

```
model_metrics <- function(cm){
  acc <- (cm[1] + cm[4]) / sum(cm[1:4])
  # accuracy = ratio of the correctly labeled subjects to the whole pool of subjects = (TP+TN)/(TP+FP+FN+TN)
  sens <- cm[4] / (cm[4] + cm[3])
  # sensitivity/recall = ratio of the correctly +ve labeled to all who are +ve in reality = TP/(TP+FN)
  spec <- cm[1] / (cm[1] + cm[2])
  # specificity = ratio of the correctly -ve labeled cases to all who are -ve in reality = TN/(TN+FP)
  err <- (cm[2] + cm[3]) / sum(cm[1:4]) #(all incorrect / all)
  metrics <- data.frame(Accuracy = acc, Sensitivity = sens, Specificity = spec, Error = err)
  return(metrics)
}
```

Now compare the results of `confusionMatrix()` to those of my function:

```
library(caret)
c_cm <- confusionMatrix(dat$real, dat$pred)
c_cm
          Reference
Prediction 0 1
         0 1 1
         1 2 5
c_cm$byClass
Sensitivity          Specificity       Pos Pred Value       Neg Pred Value            Precision               Recall 
  0.3333333            0.8333333            0.5000000            0.7142857            0.5000000            0.3333333

model_metrics(cm)
  Accuracy Sensitivity Specificity     Error
1 0.6666667   0.8333333   0.3333333 0.3333333
```

Sensitivity and specificity seem to be swapped around between my function and `confusionMatrix()`. I assumed I used the wrong formulae, but I double-checked on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Sensitivity) and I was right. I also double-checked that I was calling the right values from the confusion matrix, and I'm pretty sure I am. The `caret` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/confusionMatrix) also suggests it's using the correct formulae, so I have no idea what's going on.

Is the `caret` function wrong, or (more likely) have I made some embarrassingly obvious mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The caret function isn't wrong.

First. Consider how you construct a table. `table(first, second)` will result in a table with `first` in the rows and `second` in the columns.

Also, when subsetting a table, one should count the cells columnwise. For example, in your function the correct way to calculate the sensitivity is

```
 sens <- cm[4] / (cm[4] + cm[2])
```

Finally, it is always a good idea to read the help page of a function that doesn't give you the results you expected. `?confusionMatrix` will give you the help page.

In doing so for this function, you will find that you can specify what factor level is to be considered as a positive result (with the `positive` argument).

Also, be careful with how you use the function. To avoid confusion, I would recommend using named arguments instead of relying on argument specification by place.

The first argument is data (a factor of predicted classes), the second argument reference is a factor of observed classes (`dat$real` in your case).

To get the results you want:

```
confusionMatrix(data = dat$pred, reference = dat$real, positive = "1")

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction 0 1
         0 1 2
         1 1 5
                                          
               Accuracy : 0.6667          
                 95% CI : (0.2993, 0.9251)
    No Information Rate : 0.7778          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.8822          
                                          
                  Kappa : 0.1818          
                                          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.0000          
                                          
            Sensitivity : 0.7143          
            Specificity : 0.5000          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.8333          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.3333          
             Prevalence : 0.7778          
         Detection Rate : 0.5556          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.6667          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.6071          
                                          
       'Positive' Class : 1
```